# Может ли DPI определить какой протокол под SSL/TLS

Tags: ssl, tls, dpi

Допустим на одном порту крутиться сервисы использующие HTTPS, FTPS в пасивном режиме, IRC и еще протоколы с надстройкой SSL/TLS, может ли третья сторона узнать что я использую

Comment: Только косвенно. Как известно, телеграм блокировали по размеру пакета.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Как уже отметили в комментариях - по размеру пакетов. Пример, по control connection FTP протокол пересылает очень короткие команды, и короткие ответы. Например:

   ```
   USER anonymous
   230 User OK
   ```

   Для HTTP обычно запрос/ответ намного длиннее.
2. TLS расширение `Application-Layer Protocol Negotiation`. Используется для соединения по HTTP 2.0. Сообщение `ClientHello` указывает серверу какие протоколы будут использоваться. Например, все браузеры передают в открытом виде 2 протокола: HTTP2, HTTP1. Это нужно для того, что бы сервер, который поддерживает оба протокола мог понять, что клиент поддерживает HTTP2 без дополнительного взаимодействия, которое бы замедляло передачу данных.
3. Много имплементаций TLS передают разные расширения в `ClientHello`. Можно по передаваемым шифрам, поддерживаемым эллиптическим кривым, подписям, порядку расширений понять, какой клиент используется.